# Rsync doesn't traverse subdirectories

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to Rsync my Laravel project and this is how my `filter.txt` looks like:

```
+ app/
+ config/
+ database/
+ public/
+ resources/
+ routes/
- .env
- */
```

And I run rsync with these options: `rsync -vzcrSLhp`

The problem is if there is changed file, say in the "resources/views/" subdirectory for example, the rsync does not detect that.

How can I make it traverse all subdirectories and include everything (every depth) ?

**Second question**: I have my `filter.txt` in the current directory so I run rsync like this:

```
rsync -vzcrSLhp filter=". filter.txt"
```

Is there a way so I can put my filter file in another directory and reference to that? right now it's in `code/project/` and I move it to `code/`

I tried `filter="../ filter.txt"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured that out myself.

I should have used a lead `/` before the directory names. Also had to change `*/` to `/*/`

```
+ /app/
+ /config/
+ /database/
+ /public/
+ /resources/
+ /routes/
- .env
- /*/
```

And my second question is solved too. using `--filter=". ../filter.txt"`